# Excel Pass/Fail function with multiple variables

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have this table where I need to get Pass or Fail result.

- For column A if yes or n/a: 50% pass / no: 0% pass
- For column B if yes: 15% pass / no: 0% pass
- For column C if yes: 35% pass / no: 0% pass

Please help me to find a formula to get Pass or Fail accordingly to the above percentages.

[image: Table]

Comment: your question is unclear now. What the percentages mean? And how it's related to the picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this Formula in D2 to sum the result >0 or >=50% or your choice gives you pass
=IF(IF(OR(A2="yes",A2="n/a")=TRUE,50%,0)+IF(B2="yes",15%,0)+IF(C2="yes",35%,0)=>50%,"Pass","Fail") and drag it down

Comment: Sam, the sum will never exceed 1, so your formula always results "Fail"

Comment: I mentioned above >0 or she might write 50% she can write any number conveinient

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I have solved the issue now and got the right function. You are the best!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear. If this doesn't solve your problem, it should at least give you the tools to do so. If you clarify, I can edit my answer based on your new information. I'm going to assume that <=50% is fail, >50% is pass, and your three conditions are summed.

So, breaking down your three conditions, you get:

- =IF(A2="no",0,0.5)
- =IF(B2="yes",0.15,0)
- =IF(C2="yes",0.35,0)

Because each of these formulas simply resolve to a number, you can add them together with *SUM()*

*SUM(IF(A2="no",0,0.5),IF(B2="yes",0.15,0),IF(C2="yes",0.35,0))* will give just another number (0.35 in this case) which can be compared to your definition of passing (greater than 50%) and used in the logical test for one last IF().

The result is:

```
=IF(SUM(IF(A2="no",0,0.5),IF(B2="yes",0.15,0),IF(C2="yes",0.35,0))>0.5,"pass","fail")
```

In this case, I chose to use SUM() purely for readability purposes. You could have also just done
`=IF(IF(A2="no",0,0.5)+IF(B2="yes",0.15,0)+IF(C2="yes",0.35,0)>0.5,"pass","fail")`
but I think that's marginally harder to understand by inspection.